# python 3 iterator not executing next

Tags: python, python-itertools

Why does an iterator in python 3 support `__next__` and not `next`? Is it not supposed to be called directly but only while doing :

```
 for i in iterator:
      dosomething(i)
```

I have a use case where I would like to call `next`. For example using `itertools.count` for a stream of increasing integers. I would like to do :

```
from itertools import count
    cnt = count(0)
    one(cnt.next())
    two(cnt.next())
```

Right now I can do the above by using `__next__` which suggests to me that it is supposed to not be called externally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, use the global function [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
one(next(cnt))
```

Comment: @khelwood Well, 2.6+, but those who don't even have that face bigger problems than their iterator fu not being forward compatible.